# Terraform Acceptance Tests: "Error: Failed to read file"

Tags: terraform

I started writing acceptance tests for a terraform provider plugin.

Whenever I run them with `TF_ACC=1 go test ./... -v -parallel=4`, I randomly get errors like following:

```
Step i/n error: Error running second post-apply plan:
Error: Failed to read file

The file
"$(TMPDIR)/tftest443/work874/config340/terraform_plugin_test.tf"
could not be read

Error: Failed to read directory for module

The source directory
$(TMPDIR)/tftest443/work874/config340
could not be read
```

Running these tests subsequently throws similar errors at different steps.

**The resources are correctly created, updated and destroyed during the test though.**

Why do my tests keep throwing these errors although they succeed in creating the test resources? And what do I need to change to make them work again?

**EDIT:**

I also recreated the problem with the [hashicups example plugin](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-hashicups), adding the following acceptance test:

```golang
func TestAccResourceOrderCreateMultiStep(t *testing.T) {
    steps := []resource.TestStep{}
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        steps = append(steps, resource.TestStep{
            Config: testAccCheckHashicupsOrderConfigBasic(i + 1, 1),
        })
    }

    resource.ParallelTest(t, resource.TestCase{
        PreCheck:  func() { testAccPreCheck(t) },
        Providers: testAccProviders,
        Steps:     steps,
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your Go code for the provider as a [mcve] please?